# Mongodb replications sets...tying ot get tutorial to work

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to do the Replica Sets tutorial for mongodb.  I am using ubuntu on 64 bit and installed using sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen.

Tutorial is at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Basics

I stop the service using

```
/etc/init.d/mongodb stop
```

I then try:

```
/etc/init.d/mongodb start --rest --replSet myset
```

When I go to http://localhost:28017/_replSet I get this message.

> REST is not enabled.  use --rest to turn on. check that port 28017 is
>   secured for the network too.

So...how do I resolve?  How do I open a port on ubuntu is that is the problem?  Did I do things correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit your `/etc/mongodb.conf` file , setting `rest = true` and `replSet = myset`, and restart mongo.

Init.d script don't accept parameters. Or: `/etc/init.d/mongodb`  is not the same as `/usr/bin/mongod` - The parameters you're passing are not making it to the mongo executable.

Comment: When I set rest and replSet options in mongodb.conf then mongodb fails to start. I am on Debian, starting using init.d script. Any ideas?

Comment: read the error log / launch manually and read the error directly in your terminal. If you're still stuck: google. If you're still stuck:  ask a question. Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for reply. I have found the problem - I had mongo v. 1.4 while replSet supported in later version. Installed v 2 and now it works.